# c# Thread unactivity property

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function that reads numbers from console and writes them to queue and a massive of threads that should read numbers from queue, calculate factorials and write it to file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threadsNumber = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of threads: ");
        while ((Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out threadsNumber) == false)||(threadsNumber <= 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a positive number!");
        }
        Console.Clear();

        Queue<int> numbersQueue = new Queue<int>();
        Thread [] threadMas = new Thread[threadsNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; i++)
        {
            threadMas[i] = new Thread(() => ThreadProc.ThreadProcStart(numbersQueue));
            threadMas[i].Start();
        }
        //some code...
```

ThreadProc:

```
class ThreadProc
{
    private static object locker = new object();

    public static void ThreadProcStart(Queue<int> queue)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int num = Deq(queue); //Checks if queue is empty. If not -
                                  //Returns first element
            if (num != -1)
            {
                BigInteger bigInt = Factorial.FactTree(num); //factorical
                Writer.WriteToFile(num + " factorial: " + bigInt, "result.txt"); //write to file
            }
            else
            {
                // Here I need to add something
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static int Deq(Queue<int> queue)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                return queue.Dequeue();
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to stop all threads when all calculations are done. How can i mark thread as "unactive" when the queue is empty without actually aborting it?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your current solution.

Comment: Fall in the pit of success with the BlockingCollection class.  You can call its CompletedAdding() method to let the consumers know that the job is done.

Comment: @HansPassant When i call `CompletedAdding()` some threads may still be alive. I need to finish the programm right after all of them are finished. For that i wanted to write a function, but i don't know how to check if a thread is actually calculating something or just waiting in infinite `while(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BlockingCollection`, which underneath the covers uses `ConcurrentQueue`.  Your code will be soooo much simpler and you won't have to worry about subtle locking bugs.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int threadsNumber = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of threads: ");
    while ((Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out threadsNumber) == false) || (threadsNumber <= 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a positive number!");
    }
    Console.Clear();

    BlockingCollection<int> queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    Thread[] threadMas = new Thread[threadsNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; i++)
    {
        threadMas[i] = new Thread(ProcessQueue);
        threadMas[i].Start(queue);
    }

    string userInput = null;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput != "stop") {
            queue.Add(int.Parse(userInput)); // These numbers get process by the threads in parallel.
        }
    } while (userInput != "stop");

    queue.CompleteAdding(); // Use this to signal that no more items will be added to the queue.

    // Now the main thread exits.
    // But the program stays alive until the other threads finish
    // clearing the queue.
}

private static void ProcessQueue(object data)
{
    BlockingCollection<int> queue = (BlockingCollection<int>)data;
    foreach (var num in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) // This will automatically exit the loop once CompleteAdding is called and the queue is empty.
    {
        BigInteger bigInt = Factorial.FactTree(num); //factorical
        Writer.WriteToFile(num + " factorial: " + bigInt, "result.txt"); //write to file
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about `queue.CompleteAdding();`. Input stops when user enters "stop". But threads must start calculations when the first number is written.

Comment: Well, that part of your code was not posted, so I couldn't guess.  But basically, just start the threads, keep adding numbers to your queue (the threads will start processing them immediately).  When the user inputs "stop", then you can call `queue.CompleteAdding()`. At this point, the running threads will process any remaining numbers in the queue (the threads will not be aborted), but will not keep waiting for further numbers and will exit the `foreach` loop gracefully once the queue is cleared.  Give it a try and see.

Comment: I edited the code to give you an idea of how it would work. The main point to keep in mind is that `CompleteAdding()` doesn't abort the other threads.  It only serves as a signal to the consumers of the queue (the threads) that they should not expect more numbers to appear in the queue, and that they can gracefully exit their processing loop when they're done clearing and processing existing numbers in the queue.  The program itself will only end once all the threads complete their work and exit.

Comment: Thank you, this actually works! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer, but im really grateful.